# Does Shared Libraries always be installed into /system/libs after install the Android APK?

Tags: android, shared-libraries, apk

As the title, after install the APK, does the shared libraries inside the APK always be installed into the `/system/libs` path?

I want to use the `System.load(pathName)` to load the so, does the `pathName` always start with the `/system/libs` ?

Comment: AFAIK, they are never installed into the `/system/libs` path. Each app has its own set of `.so` files (if that APK has any in the first place).

Comment: @CommonsWare Using the System.load("/data/data/com.xxx.myproject/lib/libxxx.so") to load the so, is that always right ? libxxxx.so is always installed in APK.

Comment: I have never used `System.load(pathName)`, and so I do not know the exact expectations of `pathName`. `/data/data/com.xxx.myproject` is not necessarily going to be where your app is located, though. In particular, I would be worried about secondary user accounts on Android 4.2+ tablets/Android 5.0+ phones, plus installing to removable media on Android 6.0+.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have found a solution as the answer. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
System.load(getContext().getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir + "/libxxx.so");
```

[nativeLibraryDir](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html#nativeLibraryDir) added in API 9